# CSS animation becomes choppy / delayed in IOS

Tags: css, animation

I have a Button inside a `div` in which the tick mark appears as we click. The tick mark is added using after pseudo class. But the things looks choppy in browsers (Chrome and Safari) of iOS devices where the animation appears to be stopped and resumes after sometime.The `div` outside that contains button also has `:active` pseduo class which transforms it.

```
 //outer div contains the button 
    div:active {
      transform: scale(0.95);
    }

    // add tick with after pseudo class
    .draw:after {
      height: 60px;
      width: 30px
      content: '';
      left: 14px;
      top: 42px;
      position: absolute;
      transform-origin: left top;
      animation-duration: 300 ms;            // animation duration applied it
      transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(120deg);  // transform applied for the tick mark
      animation-name: animate-tick;
    }

    // keyframes for animation
    // animation height and width applied 
    @keyframes animate-tick {   
      0% {
        height: 0; width: 0;
      }
      40% {
        height: 0px; width: 30px;
      }
      100% {
        height: 60px; width: 30px;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added *@-webkit-keyframes*?

1. Create a named set of keyframes in CSS using the @-webkit-keyframes rule. The set must  include at least one keyframe.
2. Set the -webkit-animation-duration property to a positive, nonzero value.
3. Set the -webkit-animation-name property to the name of the set of keyframes.